# Change default Laravel Mix Minimizer/Minifier (webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-closure-compiler, laravel-mix, webpack-plugin

Is there a way to change the default minifier that Laravel Mix uses?

By default, it uses 'Terser' (the Webpack default), but I would like it to instead use Closure Compiler (see [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/closure-webpack-plugin)).

I have tried various things but have not had any luck yet. This is my latest failed attempt:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            // ...
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // ...
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // ...
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new ClosurePlugin({mode: 'STANDARD'}, {})
        ]
    }
});
```

***I would like to specifically achieve this using the `webpack.mix.js` configuration if possible i.e. I would like to avoid overriding the Laravel mix configuration (this may not be possible)***

Comment: Have you managed this to work as expected?